# MySQL: create table, primary key automatically generated?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

In mysql, how do I automatically generate primary key for a table?

If I don't specify a primary key in,

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
   ...
   ...
);
```

would mysql automatically generate primary key?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you don't specify a primary key it will not create one. To create a primary key, use the following.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
   id int NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

This will create an "id" column, make it not null, and the primary key.